# Solutions for preventing/removing raindrops on glasses when riding in rain?

Tags: rain, glasses

I have to wear glasses when riding by bike and when it rains it can become hard to see my surroundings.

Wiping them with my hand/glove makes things worse as it smudges everything.

Before I resort to wearing contact lenses, I thought I'd ask if anyone has any clever ideas on how to prevent this from happening.

[image]